# Access TextArea using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I have a website `www.example.com` where I would like to extract some specific information. This website has a text area placeholder where to add some text.
I am trying to use selenium as follows:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'https://example.com/'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('my path/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
```

The path where I can get information on Text Area should be

```
<body>
  <div class="index-wrap">==$0
...
  <div class="left-s-wrap">
   <div id="table">
    <div class="table">
     <div class="container">
      <div class="table__input"> ==$0
       ... 
       <div class="row tab">
        <div class="table__input-wrap table__input-wrap_multiline">
         <textarea placeholder="https://example.com" wrap="hard" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
          <button class="button button_accent-green">Add URLs</button>
```

Specifically the part which is going to be edited by entering urls is

```
         <textarea placeholder="https://example.com" wrap="hard" spellcheck="false">www.my_example.com</textarea>
```

I guess that I need to use find_element_by_xpath and click, similarly to this:

```
        textarea = site.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea')
        textarea.click()
```

But I am not familiar with process and I am a beginner in using these methods to access textarea.
Any help on this will be extremely helpful!

Update question:
Although I've followed the suggested method below, I cannot submit the query:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome('my path/chromedriver',chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get('https://www.example.com/')
textarea = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea')
textarea.send_keys("www.my-example.com")
```

How can I click on submit to gather information from the website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the send_keys method to send a text to the textarea.

```
textarea = site.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea')
textarea.send_keys("www.example.com")
```

And you can use these codes to extract the value of the textarea

```
textarea = site.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea').get_attribute("value")
```

or

```
textarea = site.find_element_by_xpath('//textarea').text
```

**UPDATE:** to click on the "Add URLs" button, you can use this xpath:( With assuming that there are no other buttons with the same class before "Add URLs" button)

```
//button[@class='button button_accent-green']
```

if there are other buttons with the same class before the "Add URLs" button, you can use this xpath.

```
//button[text()='Add URLs']
```

So, the clicking code will be:

```
# with using the class name
button = site.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='button button_accent-green']")
# with using the text of the button
button = site.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Add URLs']")
button.click()
```

Comment: thank you for your help and answer, Y sharifpour. Can you please have a look at my updated question after trying your method, if you do not mind? Thanks

Comment: I may need some clarification. Does the textarea get visible when you click on an "Add URL" button? So, you mean, to see the textarea and the data, you need to click on the add URL button, right?

Comment: Yes, the textarea is already visible.I am typing correctly the web on this area. To Add the URL and get information about that, there is a button (<button class="button button_accent-green">Add URLs</button>) where I should click on, after typing the text in the textarea.

Comment: I guess you have a problem with writing an XPath for the button, right? In that case, I just updated my answer and provided a solution (better say an XPath) for clicking on the button.

Comment: Thank you so much for updating your answer and help, Y sharifpour

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to send something to that text area:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//textarea[contains(@placeholder, 'https://example.com')]"))).send_keys('some text here ')
```

This is `explicitWait`, a way more reliable than `find_element_by_xpath`

**Imports:**

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

[Read more here - official docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: I did not know about this way. Thank you cruisepandey.