# Reading text from textarea in webdriver. without id and class

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

First of all, I apologize for my English. How can I access the textarea that opens when we inspect the message section. I am using C# and want to achieve with selenium. without id and class. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Check this- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68059309/access-textarea-using-selenium

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using XPath:
As your element does not have the Id you can use other attributes or target the element by its value.

e.g.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//textarea[contains(text(),'text you are looking for...')]"))
```

You can also target the element including its parent element:

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div/textarea[contains(text(),'text you are looking for...')]"))
```

Also here is a useful topic you can use to get understand the syntax of XPaths - [XPath Syntax W3](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)